# Vertical lookup between two columns with pandas (python)

Tags: python, missing-data

I would like to know if it is possible to complete the following table to obtain the expected result (to the right)

```
  X              Y          X              Y
–––––––––––––––-–-        –––––––––––––––-–-
  Argentina     AR          Argentina     AR
  Brazil       NaN          Brazil        BR
  Brazil        BR          Brazil        BR
  Canada        CA          Canada        CA
  NaN           AR          Argentina     AR
  Canada       NaN          Canada        CA
```

My intention is to replace NaNs by considering information from columns X and Y, specifically to get instances with copies country/code. Each country has just one code and viceversa.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result. Don't paste images of code or data -- it's inconvenient to make your example reproducible.

Comment: You can always use `pd.replace` or `pd.where`

Comment: The problem is to use a sort of vertical lookup (e.g. excel) to fill both columns. No idea how to do that in order to treat big data and write a more general code

Comment: Could you please type (as text) an example DataFrame and what the expected output should be? Add as many corner cases as you need for a complete spec. For example: What happens if there are more than two rows with a given label in `X`, e.g. `'Y': [1,2,Nan,3,4,NaN]`?

Comment: In my specific case I have a dataset with countries and the alpha–2 code. For instance: Algeria – DZ, Argentina – AR, United States – US, ... Every country has a specific code, but sometimes I could have missing values in 'country' and sometimes in 'alpha–2 code' and I need to fill both avoiding to perform two np.merge to complete the first column and then the second

Comment: I hope the problem is now clearer

Comment: It is better, thx. For future reference, you could specify your input sample as a copy/pastable code snippet, such as: `df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Canada', np.nan, 'Canada'], 'Y': ['AR', np.nan, 'BR', 'CA', 'AR', np.nan]})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edits**

1. the original answer using `.transform()` would break for old
   versions of `pandas` (e.g. `1.1.3`).
2. there are cases where one wants to fill missing `X` values based on `Y`, and cases where it is the opposite.
3. a simpler approach is to just get a unique mapping `X: Y`.

```py
def first_valid(g):
    return g.bfill().iloc[0]

m = df.groupby('X')['Y'].apply(first_valid)

>>> m
X
Argentina    AR
Brazil       BR
Canada       CA
Name: Y, dtype: object
```

If you like, you can fill the missing values in the original `df`, e.g. if you had a larger `df` with other columns and want to keep the same shape, just filling missing values:

```py
dct = df.groupby('X')['Y'].apply(first_valid).to_dict()
new_df = df.assign(
    X=df['X'].fillna(df['Y'].map({v:k for k, v in dct.items()})),
    Y=df['Y'].fillna(df['X'].map(dct)),
)
```

Comment: If I try to run your code (first block) it gives me an error: 'ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 6 elements', then I see in your solution the row 4 NaN NaN. Why not complete with Argentina – AR?

Comment: What exactly is in your `df` when you run the code (please indicate the output of `df.to_dict(orient='list')`). Also, what version of `pandas` are you running with?

Comment: Dataset: `df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Canada', np.nan, 'Canada'], 'Y': ['AR', np.nan, 'BR', 'CA', 'AR', np.nan]})`. The output of `df.to_dict(orient='list')` is `{'X': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Brazil', 'Canada', nan, 'Canada'], 'Y': ['AR', nan, 'BR', 'CA', 'AR', nan]}` and panda's version: `'1.1.3'`

Comment: `df.groupby('X')['Y'].transform(fill)`: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 6 elements`, then for `df.groupby('X')['Y'].apply(fill)`: `0     AR
1     BR
2     BR
3     CA
4    NaN
5     CA`

Comment: ok, it was indeed the older version of `pandas`. See updated answer (tested in both 1.1.3 and 1.4.1).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import math
 
data = {
    'X': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', None, 'C', 'C'],
    'Y': [1, None, 2, 3, 1, None, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_d = df.dropna().drop_duplicates()

for i, val in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(val['X']):
        df.loc[i, 'X'] = df_d.loc[df_d['Y'] == val['Y'], 'X'].values
    if pd.isnull(val['Y']):
        df.loc[i, 'Y'] = df_d.loc[df_d['X'] == val['X'], 'Y'].values
        
print(df)
```

First, I copied the original dataframe dropping the `NaN` values and duplicates, just to get unique rows to get its values after. Then iterate through rows in the original dataframe and check if its `NaN`, if it is, then get the value from the unique dataframe.

```
   X    Y
0  A  1.0
1  B  2.0
2  B  2.0
3  C  3.0
4  A  1.0
5  C  3.0
6  C  3.0
```